# Content inside div doesn't appear completely?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a one page website and i'm using bootstrap columns. I have a problem when i shrink the screen, the content of the form that is in `position:absolute` doesn't appear completely when i shrink the screen.

How can i make sure that the second can fit in height to show all the content ? i tried `overflow : scroll` and `overflow :visible` in the class `imageWrapper` but it doesn't fix my problem. This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdRfd.png) i want to achieve.

The Html and css code :

```css
.imageWrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.formShape {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:none;
    margin-bottom:80px;
    width:540px;
    height:650px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 left">
          Content 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img class="homePhoto" src="images/img1">
            <img class="formShape" src="images/img2">
            <div class="form" id="formContainer">
            <form>
            ...
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried scrollable:true css property for that div

Comment: There is a missing ```</div>``` in your code

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao yes i tried `overflow : scroll` and `overflow :visible` but they don't answer my question

Comment: Could you show us a diagram of the layout you're trying to build?

Comment: Now there's a ```</div>``` too much in your code …

Comment: Here is a pen. Is this what you're trying to build? https://codepen.io/HunTeR-VK/pen/qBRPqvg?editors=1100

Comment: @CharleneVas i added a diagram of the result i want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the layout and coded this - I made the below changes.

1. Added the image as a background image on the `.imagewrapper` class
2. Removed the form shape div and used the form as the shape - you can add a background image to the form if you need.

Is this what you're looking for?

(I've added the border just for reference purposes - they can be taken out)

```css
.imageWrapper {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.form {
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
    <div class="content col-12 col-md-6 left">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="form" id="formContainer">
          <form>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```